# Discord.py: Trying to do an action depending on user reaction

Tags: discord.py

This is the code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")
Token=""

@client.command()
async def react(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test")
    await message.add_reaction("<>")
    await message.add_reaction("<>")
    user=ctx.message.author
    def check(reaction, user):
        user == ctx.message.author and str(message.emoji) == ''
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')

client.run(Token)
```

The problem is that I always get an error "'await' outside async function", and the a of "reaction, user = a" get highlighted. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Looks like an indentation error.  `check` should only be one line `return user == ctx.message.author and str(message.emoji) in  ('', '')` You can look at this other example to see how to use the results of `wait_for` to choose what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58286840/6779307